# Where is the [Stage X: ...] Logging lines coming from when running Apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j2

I'm trying to identify exactly what Logger is responsible for the following kinds of lines in my apache spark logging:

```
[Stage 5:======>                                                 (24 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 5:==========>                                             (38 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 5:==============>                                         (51 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 5:==================>                                     (66 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 5:======================>                                 (80 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 5:==========================>                             (95 + 1) / 200]
```

So far, I have set the following in my log4j2.xml, which has turned off quite a bit, but not the above lines!  =)

```
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.spark" level="ERROR"/>
    <AsyncLogger name="akka" level="ERROR"/>
    <AsyncLogger name="org.spark-project" level="ERROR"/>
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.hadoop" level="ERROR"/>
    <AsyncLogger name="org.quartz" level="WARN"/>
    <AsyncLogger name="Remoting" level="ERROR"/>
    <AsyncLogger name="com.esotericsoftware" level="ERROR"/>
    <AsyncLogger name="com.databricks" level="ERROR"/>
```

Anyone know how to turn off the above mysterious logging by targeting the specific logger like I've done above for the others?

Answered below, but I wanted to add this bit for the Java specific implementation of the answer:

```
 new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().set("spark.ui.showConsoleProgress", "false"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **`spark.ui.showConsoleProgress = false`**.

Please check this Spark ticket [SPARK-4017](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4017)

Comment: I don't want to sett all logging to the Error level, though, as this configuration is shared with other parts of my application.